# Evaluating different strategies across scenarios with different success distributions. (with robots!)

Tags: regression

I am doing a real-world robot experiment where I have 10 scenarios of varying difficulty. I want to evaluate strategy 1 vs strategy 2 to see which is better. The robot gets a score for each attempt at a scenario (say weight of objects correctly moved minus weight of objects incorrectly moved).

So far I have been taking the score of all of strategy 1 and the scores of strategy 2 and calculating the 0.95 confidence intervals on them and seeing if those overlap.

However, I know that the scenarios vary quite a bit in difficulty so it seems like I could use this information to make a more powerful statistical test and get results with less data (since collecting data is expensive).

Naively, I imagine I could pair up score(strategy_1, scene_1) with score(strategy_2, scene_1) and so forth and end up with a data-set that is the deltas between (randomly associated) pairs of the strategies going "head to head" on a particular scene and then calculate the 0.95 confidence interval on those differences and see if it is significantly different from zero.

Is this valid? Is there a generally accepted strategy/algorithm for this kind of problem? (I'm ignorant enough that I feel like I don't know the right words to google to find the answer). What if I have more data from strategy 1 than strategy 2? Is there a way to incorporate that information into my test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking what to Google, as part of your question.  I've answered is such a way as to accommodate that.

You may be able to use a a two-sample t-test (to compare the means).

You can also read up of the requirements for paired t-test, to see if it applies. If you can use it, is has more power for a given sample size.

Having 95% confidence intervals that "overlap" doesn't tell you much. You want to test to see if there is a significant difference in the means, assuming you are doing parametric testing (normal distributions). Of course a confidence interval is part of significance testing.

Your distribution may require non-parametric tests.